# Was bedeutet „Nachten“ in „Weihnachten“?

Tags: meaning, etymology, gender

Ich habe mich gefragt, warum „das Weihnachten“ sächlich ist. Es kommt wahrscheinlich vom Wort „das Nachten“, aber das Wort kann ich in keinem Wörterbuch finden. Ich kann nur die Herkunft von „die Weihnacht“ finden, nicht aber vom sächlichen Wort.

Was bedeutet „das Nachten“?

Comment: Komisch, ich dachte Weihnachten ist der Plural von die Weihnacht und damit bezeichnet man als Nichtkleriker mehrere arbeitsfreie Tage.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Die Herkunft des Wortes Weihnachten ist etwas anders. Ich habe hierzu folgendes gefunden:

> „Die Form Weihnachten beruht auf einem
>   alten Dativ Plural mittelhochdeutsch
>   zu *wihen nahten* ‘in den heiligen
>   Nächten’. Damit waren ursprünglich die
>   schon in germanischer Zeit als heilig
>   gefeierten Mittwinternächte gemeint”.

Off topic, aber in diesem Zusammenhang für mich irgendwie erschütternd:

> Weihnachten wurde demnach von den
>   Germanen schon in vorchristlicher Zeit
>   gefeiert, was bedeutet, dass es
>   eigentlich gar nichts mit der Geburt
>   des CHRISTUS zu tun hat: man feierte
>   die Mittwinternächte
>   (Windersonnenwende).

Für alle, die nun genauso irritiert schauen, hier ist die [Quelle](http://www.bibelkreis.ch/themen/weihnachten.htm). (Und bestätigend: [theology.de](http://www.theology.de/kirche/kirchenjahr/weihnachten.php))

Aus den *heiligen (geweihten) Nächten* wurde damit irgendwann *Weihnachten*.
**Das** Weihnachten würde ich der Abkürzung schulden, dass es eigentlich das Weihnachtsfest heißt und der Artikel sich auf das "Fest" bezieht.

Comment: @Markus, auch "off topic": Es ist halt einfacher, vorhandene große Feste zu christianisieren, als sie abzuschaffen.

Comment: Vergleiche die Pluralbildung im Niederländischen, die i.d.R. mit "-en" arbeitet.

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt, irgendwie ist in mir schon eine kleine Welt zusammengebrochen. Was sollte ich nun meinen Kindern erzählen?! Aber das dann ein Thema für ein anderes Forum ;-)

Comment: @bot47 Ah ok, also bei dieser Anlehnung Weihnachten an Plural zu Weihnacht. Damit dann *das* Weihnachtsfest.

Comment: @Markus Ich finde es erschütternd, dass jemand über diese Information erschüttert sein kann. Das ist doch kein Geheimwissen. Kennst du keine Rauhnächte, keine Perchtenläufe, keine Wilde Jagd?

Comment: @thei Das ist wohl meiner mangelnden Beschäftigung mit der Kirche geschuldet. Ich kenne nichts von dem zitierten. Ich werde mir das bei Gelegenheit mal komplett durchlesen :-)

Comment: @Markus: Da gibt's noch viele andere Beispiele. Gut nachvollziehen kann man das auch bei den moderneren Missionierungen, z.B. wenn man sich die "Heiligen" in Südamerika anschaut. Ein paar Stichworte zum Googlen: der "Day of the Dead" in Mexiko, Sara la Kali & Durga, Isiskult & Marienverehrung, Osterfeuer.

Comment: Der Termin für Weihnachten fällt nur "zufällig" mit dem germanischen Feiern der Wintersonnwende zusammen, weil in Rom ebenfalls dieses Fest gefeiert wurde, als Fest von Sol Invictus, des unbesiegten Sonnengottes. Mit der constantinischen Wende wurde Jesus zu Sol Invictus umgedeutet und das Fest umgeweiht. Die Wintersonnwende lässt sich auch gut an der Darstellung von Krippen festmachen.

Comment: @Residuum Aber das Fest von Sol Invictus zur Wintersonnenwende zu feiern ist wohl auch eher weniger zufällig, oder?

Answer (score 6):

Weihnachten kommt vom Plural von Nacht und wird durchaus regional und in Phrasen als Plural behandelt:

`Letzte Weihnachten waren wir auf den Malediven.` (nicht: Letztes Weihnachten)

`Frohe Weihnachten!`

`Weiße Weihnachten`

Die sächliche Form wird vor allem dann verwendet, wenn von Weihnachten ohne bestimmten Artikel gesprochen wird:

`Weihnachten ist das schönste Fest überhaupt.`

Ähnliches zur Verwendung gilt für Ostern und Pfingsten, nur weiße Pfingsten sind eher unüblich.